# Can't Import Bert_Text after installing it successfully

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, cpu-word, tensorflow2.0

Bert is very powerful model for text classification but implementation of bert requires much more code than any other model. bert-text is pypi package to provide developer a ready-to-use solution.I have installed it properly.When I have tried to import ,it is throwing error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bert_text'.I have properly written the name bert_text.
I have tried it in Kaggle,Colab and local machine but the error is same.

Answer (score 2):

Hey as this is a refactor made by Yan Sun, This issue is already pending, you can go to this link and subscribe for an update when the developers will provide its solution. https://github.com/SunYanCN/bert-text/issues/1